# Access the random value of parent class

Tags: php, class

So, let's say I have this dummy code in one file:

```
<?php
class Dice
{
    public $maxPossibleNo;
    public $secretNumber;

    function __construct($no_of_dice=1) 
    {
        // how many possible dice number to enroll
        $this->maxPossibleNo = $no_of_dice * 6;

        // do shaking dice
        $this->secretNumber = $this->getSecretNumber();
    }

    function getSecretNumber() 
    {
        return rand(1, $this->maxPossibleNo);
    }

    function roll() 
    {
        $found = false;
        list($array1, $array2) = array_chunk(range(1, $this->maxPossibleNo), ceil($this->maxPossibleNo/2));
        /*
            Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
            )
            Array
            (
                [0] => 4
                [1] => 5
                [2] => 6
            )
        */

        $guess = new Guess();
        echo $this->secretNumber;
        echo $guess->checkSecretNumber();
    }
}

class Guess extends Dice
{
    function checkSecretNumber() 
    {
        return $this->secretNumber;
    }

    function isGreaterThan($x) 
    {
        return $x > $this->secretNumber;
    }

    function isLessThan($x) 
    {
        return $x < $this->secretNumber;
    }

    function isEqual($x) 
    {
        return $x == $this->secretNumber;
    }
}

$game = new Dice('1');
$game->roll();
```

Result:

```
65
43
54
```

Expected Result:

```
66
33
55
```

I want the Guess class to be able to access the secret number of the `Dice` class without having to roll it again. So I can manipulate the `Guess` class with other function.

EDIT:

> Expectation flow: The main class will only called once (to generate
>   the secret number), while i will need to do loop checking for the
>   secret number for many times. (I guess the way is to create another
>   class of it, and it will be able to be called repeatly for auto
>   checking purpose, but i had did mistake here and dont have any idea
>   how to correct this part.)

Any suggested correction will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: when you create a new Guess(), it runs the constructor of Dice automatically, since Guess extends dice. The secret number in the Guess instance is not the secret number of the first Dice instance, it's a separate instance. I think your design is flawed. Why does Guess need to extend Dice? A guess is not logically a different implementation of a Dice (which is what you'd (logically) normally use subclasses for). You probably need to instantiate Guess in your main program, and Guess should either create an instance of Dice to use, or get an instance passed in via its constructor.

Comment: Yes i also think my design is flawed. I just can't think how should be the proper way to do it. You have any design suggestion for me, pls?

Comment: well I already suggested one above

Comment: I want to know, if it is possible to access the parent class without randoming the number again. How is the proper way to do it?

Comment: I'm saying don't have it as a parent class. That's not the right design. Like I already suggested, I would instantiate Guess directly in your main program, and then either a) Guess should create an instance of Dice to use, or b) Guess should get an instance of Dice passed in via its constructor. Which option you choose will depend on how you need things to work - you haven't explained the full flow of how the program should operate

Comment: I've added a sample answer to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create a new Guess(), it runs the constructor of Dice automatically, since Guess extends dice. The secret number in the Guess instance is not the secret number of the first Dice instance, it's a separate instance. I think your design is flawed. Why does Guess need to extend Dice? A guess is not logically a different implementation of a Dice (which is what you'd (logically) normally use subclasses for).

Here's how I would do it (without knowing anything further about what exactly you want to achieve):

```
<?php
class Dice
{
  public $maxPossibleNo;
  public $secretNumber;

  function __construct($no_of_dice=1) 
  {
    // how many possible dice number to enroll
    $this->maxPossibleNo = $no_of_dice * 6;

    // do shaking dice
    $this->secretNumber = $this->getSecretNumber();
  }

  function getSecretNumber() 
  {
    return rand(1, $this->maxPossibleNo);
  }

  function roll() 
  {
    $found = false;
    list($array1, $array2) = array_chunk(range(1, $this->maxPossibleNo), ceil($this->maxPossibleNo/2));
    /*
        Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )
        Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )
    */
  }
}

class Guess
{
  private $dice;

  function __construct(Dice $d)
  {
    $this->dice = $d;
  }

  function checkSecretNumber() 
  {
    return $this->dice->secretNumber;
  }

  function isGreaterThan($x) 
  {
    return $x > $this->dice->secretNumber;
  }

  function isLessThan($x) 
  {
    return $x < $this->dice->secretNumber;
  }

  function isEqual($x) 
  {
    return $x == $this->dice->secretNumber;
  }
}

$dice = new Dice('1');
$dice->roll();
$guess = new Guess($dice);
echo $dice->secretNumber;
echo $guess->checkSecretNumber();
```

Comment: Wonderful, it works just like what i want.. Thanks a lot dude, you lighten my hours ahead.. Thank you for helping me such a junior one. ;)